# How to omit the displaying schema in xml generated in informatica

Tags: xml, xsd, informatica

Below is the format I get xml is generated through xsd definition in informatica.
I was able to eliminate the xsi:schemaLocation by editing namepace to null.
Now how do I eleminate the xmlns:xsi and xlmns:stl fromthe xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TRANSPORT xmlns:xsi="http://www.XXXXX_XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://www.xxxxxx/stl-1.0" 
dddddd="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy">
abc
</TRANSPORT>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a xsl transform which eleminates extra namespaces from your xml? Is that possible in your case?

Comment: Am not sure about the xsl usage in informatica, but have used edit namesapce defined in schema property in my target definition and was successfully able to eliminate the schema location.  But am not able to find where xmlnx:xsi and xmlns:stl are defined in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above should be handled in a post session command. 
I have used sed command in order to replace the string with null.
As the string has escape character's related to sed function like ",/ .  \ is to be used before every escape character.
example to replace a string standalone="no" with null use below command.

```
sed -i 's/standalone=\"no\"//' <filename.xml>
```